# Find classes not implementing hashCode

Tags: java

I have a project with quite some classes and it provides different answer when I run with `Debug` compare to `Run` in Intellij. Correct answer, but different, in both cases.

I suspect that there is one or more classes not implementing `hashCode` that is the cause of the difference. We use hash-based collections in several places.

How can I easily find the classes that do not implement `hashCode` without resorting to go through them manually?

Comment: It would probably be easier to find classes that *do* override `hashCode()`.

Comment: "Correct answer, but different, in both cases." If it's correct, what's the problem? I know some versions of .NET deliberately changed string hash code algorithms based on whether you were running in debug mode or not - I don't know of Java doing the same, but it would be valid to do so. If you're relying on hash codes being stable across multiple runs, then that's a bug.

Comment: Not every class that's used in HashMap etc needs to have `hashCode()` implemented. Instead, think of all your classes as belonging to one of two categories. The first, value-based classes, includes String and Integer. Two integers, both value 1234, are considered the same irrespective of whether or not they are different objects. On the other hand, identity-based class objects are distinct from each other even if they have the same value. If you and I were both named Fred, that wouldn't make us the same person. Identity classes don't have to override `equals()` and `hashCode()`.

Comment: Google's Java compiler uses a tool called [Error Prone](http://errorprone.info) to catch a whole raft of errors at compile time. I know that it considers [classes overriding `equals` without also overriding `hashCode`](http://errorprone.info/bugpattern/EqualsHashCode) to be a likely error. Is that your problem, rather simply not implementing `hashCode`?

Comment: Thanks for comments and answer. The culprit turned out to be an enum used in the `hashCode` calculation. The hashCode of enums is based on the address of the object which changes between Debug and Release. It was important to have the same behaviour for debugging reasons.

Comment: If your code is order-sensitive, you should use an ordered collection instead of relying on undocumented hash-based ordering.

Answer (score 1):

You could try running it with a custom class loader the prints classes that do not override hashCode. Run with `-Djava.system.class.loader=my.package.HashFindingLoader`

```
package my.package;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class HashFindingLoader extends ClassLoader {

    public HashFindingLoader(ClassLoader parent) {
        super(parent);
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> loadClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        Class<?> c = super.loadClass(name);

        //filters out librry classes, adjust as necessary
        if(!c.getPackage().getName().matches("^(java|sun).*")){        
            Method hashCode;
            try {
                hashCode = c.getMethod("hashCode");
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException|SecurityException ex) {
               throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
            if (hashCode.getDeclaringClass().equals(Object.class)){
                System.out.printf("%s does not override hashCode%n", c);
            }
        }
        return c;
    }

}
```